# VS2012 Suddenly starts showing "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." exception

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am running an application on Vs 2012 , working on it for 2 days now . Everything runs fines and suddenly i start seeing this error:

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I have tried the fixes as mentioned but still same thing, what troubles me that it runs fine and while running on one of the run i see the above error and now it wont go away?

All i remember doing was switching from .Net 4.5 -> 4 before this.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers i overlooked worked....

I changed Configurations

FROM

```
Build ->Platform Target = Any CPU
```

TO

```
  Build ->Platform Target = x86
```

And surprisingly it started working again , still confused as why this happened because i never changed this but this worked for me.

Thank you